# Search bar disappears on tap

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am trying to implement `UISearchDisplayController` searchBar on a view not having a `navigationbar` on it, my searchBar fixed as
`[self.view addSubview:searchBar]` and framed above the `UITableView` having contact numbers. When I tap on searchBar my `UISearchBar` disappears and the table scrolls up.

Comment: try simply using a `UISearchBar`

Comment: [`UISearchDisplayController`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisearchdisplaycontroller) has been deprecated, use [`UISearchController`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisearchcontroller)